# Modal Navigation and close

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have two scenarios

1. Opening a modal and after some navigation inside the modal, I need to close the modal however when I call `this.$modal.close()` in the last page of navigation utilising always the same `frame` the modal does not close.
2. Is there a way where you have multiple modals (one opening the next one) and at the last one, close them all? On android I just wait for each modal promise to be fulfilled but on iOS this does not work.

Here is a sample of both scenarios https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=OVxmoC&v=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `this.$modal.close()` only form the root of modal component, if you call it from any other nested levels, it will be simply ignored. If you really want to close the modal after navigation, I think you must pass the `$modal` reference down the navigation tree, may be via `props`. You may even consider using Event Bus / Global Service if that's easier for you.

**Modal.vue**

```
           this.$navigateTo(Secondary, {
                frame: "modal-frame",
                props: {
                    parentModal: this.$modal
                }
            });
```

**Secondary.vue**

```
export default {
    props: ["parentModal"],
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    methods: {
        onTap: function() {
            if (this.parentModal) this.parentModal.close();
            else this.$modal.close();
        }
    }
};
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=OVxmoC&v=3)

Comment: In case anyone got confused about this like me, the type of $modal is Object(in case you have to specify the type in your props as in: props:{ modal: Object, ... }